# "rabin2 -E" and "afll" no output for an exe file

Tags: radare2

```
    $ rabin2 -I test.exe
    arch     x86
    baddr    0x400000
    binsz    3229424
    bintype  pe
    bits     32
    canary   false
    retguard false
    class    PE32
    cmp.csum 0x0031d950
    compiled Fri Jun 19 18:22:17 1992
    crypto   false
    endian   little
    havecode true
    hdr.csum 0x0031d950
    laddr    0x0
    lang     c
    linenum  true
    lsyms    true
    machine  i386
    maxopsz  16
    minopsz  1
    nx       false
    os       windows
    overlay  true
    pcalign  0
    pic      false
    relocs   true
    signed   true
    sanitiz  false
    static   false
    stripped false
    subsys   Windows GUI
    va       true
            


    $ rabin2 -E test.exe
        [Exports]
        
        nth paddr vaddr bind type size lib name
        ________________________________________

$ radare2 test.exe 
 -- Enhance your graphs by increasing the size of the block and graph.depth eval variable.
[0x0040a5f8]> afll
[0x0040a5f8]>
```

Can anyone say why there is no output when execute `rabin2 -E test.exe` and `afll` ?
What should I try next?
I am a total beginner, in using radare2/rabin2.

Regards.

Comment: For radare2 you need to do the analysis first, so execute `aaa` before executing `afll`.

Comment: Thank you very much @PawełŁukasik . It is working now. Can you please help, also with `rabin2 -E` command, why the command has no output? Best wishes.

Comment: are you sure there are any exports? `afll` and '-E` in rabin2 are not equivalent commands, to see exports in `radare2` execute `iE`